# Better way to use Waypoints when classes need to be added dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm using Waypoints and Animate.css on elements as the user scrolls. It looks and works great, however my JS file looks messy since I have to also add the classes with JS as they can't be in the markup on this project. I'm pretty new to jQuery but I feel like there has to be a better, more DRY way of accomplishing what I'm doing!

Below is a portion of my scripts file that adds the classes and interacts with the Waypoint class–it gets really long due to the amount of things being animated. Any help pointing me the right way will be greatly appreciated!

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.section-content').css('opacity', 0).waypoint(function() {
            $('.section-content').addClass('delay animated fadeInUp');
        }, {
            offset: '100%'
        });

        $('.three-modules .module').css('opacity', 0).waypoint(function() {
            $('.three-modules .module').addClass('delay animated fadeInUp');
        }, {
            offset: '75%'
        });

        $('.section-title').css('opacity', 0).waypoint(function() {
            $('.section-title').addClass('delay animated fadeInUp');
        }, {
            offset: '75%'
        });

        $('.content-image-section').css('opacity', 0).waypoint(function() {
            $('.content-image-section').addClass('delay animated fadeInLeft');
        }, {
            offset: '75%'
        });
        $('.quiz-image-container').css('opacity', 0).waypoint(function() {
            $('.quiz-image-container').addClass('delay animated fadeInRight');
        }, {
            offset: '75%'
        });

        // …keeps going like this
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to write the same thing more concisely?

Comment: Yeah exactly! I feel like this file is getting messy and long and basically doing the same thing with minor differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to reduce repetition in the code above, you could stick the repeated code in a function with parameters for the bits that change, eg

```
function animateElementOffset(query, class, offset) {
    $(query).css('opacity', 0).waypoint(function() {
        $(query).addClass('delay animated ' + class);
    }, {
        offset: offset
    });
}

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        animateElementOffset('.section-content', 'fadeInUp', '100%');
        animateElementOffset('.three-modules .module', 'fadeInUp', '75%');
        animateElementOffset('.section-title', 'fadeInUp', '75%');
        animateElementOffset('.content-image-section', 'fadeInLeft', '75%');
        animateElementOffset('.quiz-image-container', 'fadeInRight', '75%');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Additionally, if you're repeatedly using the same elements, it might be worth it to centralize the queries that match each element, eg

```
function getAnimationHandle(query) {
    var element = $(query);
    return {
        animateOffset: function (class, offset) {
            element.css('opacity', 0).waypoint(function() {
                $(query).addClass('delay animated ' + class);
            }, {
                offset: offset
            });
        }
    }
}

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var sectionContent = getAnimationHandle('.section-content');
        var threeModulesModule = getAnimationHandle('.three-modules .module');
        var sectionTitle = getAnimationHandle('.section-title');
        var contentImageSection = getAnimationHandle('.content-image-section');
        var quizImageContainer = getAnimationHandle('.quiz-image-container');

        sectionContent.animateOffset('fadeInUp', '100%');
        threeModulesModule.animateOffset('fadeInUp', '75%');
        sectionTitle.animateOffset('fadeInUp', '75%');
        contentImageSection.animateOffset('fadeInLeft', '75%');
        quizImageContainer.animateOffset('fadeInRight', '75%');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Joshua, that's exactly what I was looking for! This will help me in the future to think more concisely. The only problem I'm running into now is a console error stating:  Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode—never encountered that before so I googled around and added 'use strict'; to the function but still experiencing the problem.

Comment: are you just using vanilla javascript?  "function" is 100% allowed in js and the code above doesn't have let, const, or class anywhere

Comment: Yeah, using vanilla JS on a WordPress site. Adding 'use strict' then throws an error on the function line with “Unexpected , ”. Trying to sort through it now!

Comment: ah, the problem was with 'class' as it's a reserved word—renamed it and works like a charm :)

Thanks!